# import sigma into vuejs + webpack project

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-component, sigma.js

I'm trying to use sigma.js in a vue component using webpack.
I installed sigma with npm and then I added in my main.js file the following lines:

```
import sigma from 'sigma'
Vue.prototype.$sigma = sigma
```

Now I'm trying to use sigma in the component file but trying with

```
sigma.parsers.json('data.jason', {container:'sigma-container'})
```

I got error. 
I tried also to substitute sigma with:

```
this.sigma
```

and with:

```
this.$sigma()
```

but I still got errors